# postgres segfault and returns SQLSTATE 08006

Tags: postgresql

I'm seeing the following error from Postgres while running some automated tests:

```
2020-03-06 23:32:57,051 WARN  main c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-2 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@42e3ede4 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0) {}
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:335)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:94)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.execute(AbstractDMLQuery.java:738)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:350)
    at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.fetchOne(InsertImpl.java:1061)
...
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1952)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    ... 53 more
2020-03-06 23:32:57,067 DEBUG main i.p.d.HikariPostgresDataSourceFactory - Connecting to jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/REDACTED as REDACTED {}
2020-03-06 23:32:57,093 ERROR main c.z.h.p.HikariPool - HikariPool-14 - Exception during pool initialization. {}
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:405)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:263)
```

Looking at `dmesg` I see there is a segfault going on:

```
[1383242.997083] postgres[7998]: segfault at 100000048 ip 000055c587913e4b sp 00007fffa492e6f0 error 4 in postgres[55c587424000+72d000]
```

This is the backtrace I obtained with `gdb`:

```
Core was generated by `postgres: REDACTED REDACTED 127.0.0.1(49990) INSERT                          '.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000055c587913e4b in pfree ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055c587913e4b in pfree ()
#1  0x000055c587687475 in ExecSetSlotDescriptor ()
#2  0x000055c58767eb61 in ExecConstraints ()
#3  0x000055c5876a0efc in ?? ()
#4  0x000055c5876a2085 in ?? ()
#5  0x000055c58767cd1b in standard_ExecutorRun ()
#6  0x000055c5877d22e5 in ?? ()
#7  0x000055c5877d2538 in ?? ()
#8  0x000055c5877d2855 in ?? ()
#9  0x000055c5877d3427 in PortalRun ()
#10 0x000055c5877cfeec in PostgresMain ()
#11 0x000055c5874ddd37 in ?? ()
#12 0x000055c58775a882 in PostmasterMain ()
#13 0x000055c5874df0e5 in main ()
```

This is my version of Postgres:

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                                   version                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
```

Anybody knows if this is a bug or if there is a workaround?

Comment: Can you reproduce the case? By re-running the same query or queries?

Comment: It is a full test suite that I can run to reproduce the crash every time. But there are many tests so knowing exactly which "insert" causes the crash would take time (the crash is not local, but in a CI server). If that would be necessary, I can work towards finding the "insert", but it will take substantial time, so is there another way?

Comment: By the way, other test suites in other schemas of the same database server work fine.

Comment: Shouldn't the CI already have extensive logs, so you just have to see what query was run last? Or activate query logging in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @A.Scherbaum added an answer below. I managed to find the offending query, this looks like a bug in Postgres.

Comment: Why does your default partition have a constraint on it? Please send this case to the PostgreSQL bugs list.

Comment: The constraint is there because of historical reasons, not needed anymore, and not very interesting but: this partition was already quite large when we introduced partitions, but in Postgres 10 there were no "default" partitions, so when this partition was first added we needed to specify some range, using the constraint helped Postgres to not re-check the partition range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enabled query logging and managed to find the offending "insert":

```
insert into "myschema"."mytable" ("custcode", "custcar", "custdob", "closed") values ('a33113f2-930c-47de-95a6-b9e07650468a', 'hellow world', '2020-02-02 01:00:00+00:00', 'f')
```

That is a partitioned table on the "custdob" column, with these partitions:

```
\d+ mytable
                                                           Table "myschema.mytable"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('mytable_id_seq'::regclass)    | plain    |              | 
 custcode   | uuid                     |           | not null |                                        | plain    |              | 
 custcar    | character varying        |           | not null |                                        | extended |              | 
 custdob    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                        | plain    |              | 
 closed     | boolean                  |           | not null | false                                  | plain    |              | 
Partition key: RANGE (custdob)
Partitions: mytable_201902_partition FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-02-01 00:00:00+00') TO ('2019-03-01 00:00:00+00'),
            mytable_201903_partition FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-03-01 00:00:00+00') TO ('2019-04-01 00:00:00+00'),
            mytable_201908_partition FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-08-02 00:00:00+00') TO ('2019-09-01 00:00:00+00'),
            mytable_202003_partition FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-03-01 00:00:00+00') TO ('2020-04-01 00:00:00+00'),
            mytable_202004_partition FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-04-01 00:00:00+00') TO ('2020-05-01 00:00:00+00'),
            mytable_000000_partition DEFAULT
```

Notice the INSERT wants to insert in February's partition, but taht partition is missing in my CI server, so it should insert the row in the DEFAULT partition. The issue is, the DEFAULT partition has this constraint:

```
"mytable_partition_check" CHECK (custdob < '2019-08-02 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
```

So Postgres seems to be getting into a bug because it can't insert a record for February while that constraint is in there. If I drop this constraint and re-issue the offending INSERT, it works this time.

Comment: I filed this bug here [Postgres Bug 16293](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16293-26f5777d10143a66%40postgresql.org)

Comment: I am also getting the same error in Spring Boot v2.5.x while using Spring Batch, is there any solution for this?

Comment: That bug has [already been patched](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20200323220502.yzkkmisx4igmiwen%40alap3.anarazel.de) in version 10 and 11. If you are getting the same error in those or newer versions I suggest you open a Postgres bug as it may be a different one.